# Can I use gradient boosting algorithm for a data with time (year) and latitudes and longitudes as predictors?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, gbm, data-science

I have a data with weekly weather information, yield , latitudes and longitudes from year 2005-2014. I would like to predict yields for 2015 based on this data. I am planning to use gradient boosting algorithm, but I am not sure if that's the right approach since I am also considering the location (lat-lon) and year as a predictor. I want to keep the data for different years so that I can capture the weather variation in different years

Comment: If your data is just 3-dimensional you should be actually able to plot it, see exactly what is happening and give nearly perfect answer, probably even using simple KNN. You should never start analyzing the problem using complex methods. Always start from the simpliest ones - I would be suprised if for such problem the simplest ones will not be the best ones

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear before, my number of data points is around 10000 and the features are around 70 variables. It's a non linear problem so using linear regression makes no sense. I tried random forest, but it was giving me bad results. I thought of using gbm and train the weak learners and see how it performs. but I am not sure if having spatial and time related is a good approach. I want to keep the data for different years so that I can capture the weather variation in different years.

Comment: This kind of data is not a problem for gbm as such

Comment: So gbm will be able to capture weather variation for different years if I consider year as a feature too?

Comment: I do not know what it will capture as it depends on your data. What i do know is that there is Nottingham specjalnie in this kind of data which might case a particular trouble to gbm